# Wrong results for bigger values

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying a programming problem, the statement is
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Like this we have to find the sum of multiples for 't' test cases with 'n' value each, I have tried to find the solution and my code is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long t,n,sum;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        t=in.nextLong();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            sum=0;
            n=in.nextLong();
            long l3=0,l5=0,l15=0;
            for(int j=3;j>0;j--)
                if((n-j)%3==0&&j<n)
                {
                l3=n-j;
                break;
            }
            for(int j=5;j>0;j--)
                if((n-j)%5==0&&j<n)
                {
                l5=n-j;
                break;
            }
            for(int j=15;j>0;j--)
                if((n-j)%15==0&&j<n)
                {
                l15=n-j;
                break;
            }

            sum+=(float)(((float)l3/(float)3)/(float)2)*(float)(l3+3);

            sum+=(float)(((float)l5/(float)5)/(float)2)*(float)(l5+5);

            sum-=(float)(((float)l15/(float)15)/(float)2)*(float)(l15+15);
            System.out.println(sum);    

        }
    }
}
```

And the input I gave was,

```
12
10
11
12
13
1000
1001
1002
1003
100000000
100000001
100000002
100000003
```

Here 12 is the number of test cases.

And the output I got was

```
23
33
33
45
233168
234168
234168
235170
2333333593784320
2333333593784320
2333333593784320
2333333593784320
```

The problem here is the answer is correct for values in the test case 10,11,12,13,1000,1001,1002,1003 but the output is wrong for remaining bigger inputs. I cant find what i am missing. Could you please help me on why I am getting this kind of wrong result and how to rectify it.

Comment: Just as  side note, instead of casting every integer to float, just add`.0f` to the end of the integer. Example `12` to `12.0f`. Also any basic arithmetic operation involving integer and float already resolves to float. In other words, only 1 of these casted values, respecting order of operations, needs to be float

Comment: This would be simpler with integer arithmetic. Remember that `n/3` truncates, so (for positive n) it is the largest integer no greater than n/3. That's precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a higher precision and a larger numbers by using BigDecimal and BigInteger:

```
package test;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long t,n;
        BigInteger sum;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        t=in.nextLong();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
            n=in.nextLong();
            long l3=0,l5=0,l15=0;
            for(int j=3;j>0;j--)
                if((n-j)%3==0&&j<n)
                {
                    l3=n-j;
                    break;
                }
            for(int j=5;j>0;j--)
                if((n-j)%5==0&&j<n)
                {
                    l5=n-j;
                    break;
                }
            for(int j=15;j>0;j--)
                if((n-j)%15==0&&j<n)
                {
                    l15=n-j;
                    break;
                }

            BigDecimal x = BigDecimal.valueOf(l3)
            .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(6))
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(l3+3));
            sum=sum.add(x.toBigIntegerExact());
            x = BigDecimal.valueOf(l5)
            .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(10))
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(l5+5));
            sum=sum.add(x.toBigIntegerExact());
            x = BigDecimal.valueOf(l15)
            .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(30))
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(l15+15));
            sum=sum.subtract(x.toBigIntegerExact());

            System.out.println(sum);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hoffner Thank for your solution. It solved my problem. Just needed a little edit at last part. But the solution to use BigInteger and BigDecimal got my solution.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I also edited it now to remove some unecessary assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Without deeper analysis of your code I would guess the problem is that you are using float, which has a quite short value range. Could you try double instead? Not sure what the correct answer would be, but at least you get different results (I just tried)

Comment: Actually, it is not so much the value range but the precision of only about 6 decimal digits that causes problems here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution looks too complex for such a task. I don't understand why do you need to perform the divisions at the end. You can try the following code:

```
int t = <some number> // the upper bound
int[] dividers = [...] // those are divisors against which we have to test
long sum = 0;
// check all the number up the bound
for (int number = 1; number < t; number++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dividers.length; i++) {
        if (number % dividers[i] == 0) {
             // the number is divisible without remainder -> add it to the sum
             sum += number;
             break;
        }
    }    
}
```

The idea is to iterate all the numbers you want to check and see if they are divisible by some of the N dividers. If you find a number, you add it to the sum and continue with the next one.

**Edit:**
After the clarifications from OP, I came up with another way to do this.

```
int t = <some number> // the upper bound
int dividers = [3, 5];
int dividerProduct = dividers[0] * dividers[1];
long sum = calculateSumForDivider(dividers[0], t) + calculateSumForDivider(dividers[1], t) - calculateSumForDivider(dividerProduct, t);

public static int calculateSumForDivider(int divider, int number) {
    int n = number / divider;
    return divider * n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

What is the logic behind all this?
By dividing the target number, we can calculate how many times does the divider "fit" in the target. This is also the number of numbers in the interval [1, number] that are divisible by the divider. Let's see an example:

```
t = 10, divider = 3
10 / 3 = 3, so they are 3 numbers in the interval [1, 10], divisible by 3
the numbers are: 1 * 3, 2 * 3, 3 * 3
if we calculate the sum we get 1 * 3 + 2 * 3 + 3 * 3 = 3 * (1 + 2 + 3) = 18

analogically, for = 10, divider = 5
10 / 5 = 2
1 * 5 + 2 * 5 = 5 * (1 + 2) = 15
```

As a conclusion, we have the following formula for the sum:

```
sum = divider * n * (n + 1) / 2
```

where `n` is the result of the division.

The gotcha here is that numbers, divisible by both 3 and 5 (in other words divisible by 15) are going to be added twice to the sum. To correct this we use the same formula as above to calculate their sum and subtract it from the resulting some, reaching the result.

This solution will only work well for 2 dividers, since with multiple the number of numbers that will be added multiple times to the sum will grow exponentially. F.e. if we want to divide be 3, 4 or 5, we will need to take care of 12, 15, 20, 60, etc.

This will also not work if the two one of the dividers is a power of the other, like 3 and 9. In that case we only need the numbers, divisible by 3.

Comment: I think the point of his more complex solution is that is faster but I didn't understand it fully yet :-)

Comment: Since he uses a ton of float operations I am pretty sure it isn´t faster. And Danail´s answer has <entered_number>*<number_of_dividors> operations.
I think there is not much room for optimization ;-)

Comment: The solution would be correct for your code @Danail Alexiev . I have tried your solution but it is very time consuming as my test case range is 10^5 and value is of range 10^9.

Comment: @abdulrahman Does the task specify what must we do with duplicate numbers? For example, if t = 20 and the dividers are 3 and 5, should 15 be included in the sum once or twice?

Comment: @abdulrahuman Also, is the number of dividers always 2, or it can be a random number > 0?

Comment: @Danail Alexiev you should include 15 only once. Yeah, for this problem only 2 divisors which is 3 and 5.

Comment: @abdulrahuman After your clarifications, I came up with another solution. It uses only int math, so it should run into correctness problems. Eventually you may want to change some things from `int` to `long`, based on your test range.

Comment: @Danail Alexiev what do you mean by int to long? I have used only long variables

Comment: @DanailAlexiev Thank you for your solution. Your concept was correct. But I got the solution with the use of BigInteger and BigDecimal. The problem was that the sum got way beyond long and now solved with BigDecimal and BigInteger. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your algorithm because the simplest one should be like:

```
 sum=0;
     n=100100000;

     for(int j=1;j<n;j++)
         if(j%3==0 || j%5==0)
         {
             sum+=j;
         }
     System.out.println(sum);   
     System.out.println(n*n);
```

And to get a better idea on what should be the result, it is always less than `n*n`.

The output I found was:

```
2338002249916668
10020010000000000
```

So, as your results where less than `n*n`, if you are sure about you algorithm, then they are correct.

Comment: The solution would be correct for your code @Tiyeb Bellal . I have tried your solution but it is very time consuming as my test case range is 10^5 and value is of range 10^9.